# 6 channel PWM with USB support

Tags: microcontroller, pic, avr, pwm

I am looking for a IC with mininum 6 channel PWM output and preferably USB support so that I can control it uing a software. Any ideas ?

Comment: You're telling us very little about your actual requirements. Most microcontroller manufacturers have a selection guide on their website. So does Atmel, which gives a wealth of controllers that satisfy your requirements. One example is http://www.atmel.com/devices/AT90USB1286.aspx?tab=parameters The selection guide is in the left blue column on the same page.

Comment: Getting something with usb support is difficult, you'll have to opt for USB to UART interface.

Comment: I actually need to control around 5 motors via PWM output. These outputs are in turn controlled by a window program. The whole system communicates via USB. I initially thought using PIC18F4550 but it has 2 PWM channels. Even i cannot use digital pins as PWM output.

Comment: @perilbrain hardly.  USB enabled micros are all over the place.

Comment: I'd say ATMeaga32u4 or stm32fXXXX

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention other requirements, like Flash and RAM size, and other I/Os, so I'll have just to take a shot at it. For most parts Digikey has very good selection tools, but microcontrollers are a bit of a let-down: you can't select for USB separately, for instance, only combined with other features, which makes the selection process rather involved. Also no selection on PWMs.

But like *jippie* says you can find information on manufacturers' sites. On the [Atmel parametric search page](http://www.atmel.com/PFResults.aspx#%28data%3a%28area%3a%27%27,category%3a%2734864%27,pm%3a!%28%28i:8238,v%3a!%280,18%29%29,%28i:8394,v%3a!%280,17%29%29,%28i:8362,v%3a!%281,28%29%29,%28i:8282,v%3a!%28%29%29%29,view%3atable%29,sc:1%29) I found for instance the [AT32UC3A](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc32058.pdf):

- Full Speed USB + USB-on-the-go
- 7 PWM channels
- 128 KB to 512 KB Flash
- 32 KB or 64 KB SRAM
- 100 or 144 pin QFP, 144 pin BGA

If this is not the device you're looking for, then please update the question, or have a look at the parametric search page I linked to.

Comment: To add to the AVR side of the war, [LUFA](http://www.fourwalledcubicle.com/LUFA.php) ((Lightweight USB Framework for AVRs) is free open and applicable to smaller (read DIP - easy to solder at home) arv-s.

Answer (score 1):

Since you already seem to work with PICs, have a look at Microchips [Product Selector](http://www.microchip.com/productselector/MCUProductSelector.html). If you select 4+ PWM channels and USB, you get 105 products. 47 of them (if I counted right) have more than 5 PWM channels (in fact, 9 channels or more - there are no PICs in the list with exactly 6 PWM channels).

For example, the PIC18FxxJ53/94 series should be somewhat similar to the 18F4550. A good candidate for you should be the [PIC18F26J53](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en548696), as it comes in a 28 pin DIP package (most of the other ones have 64 pins or more).

Comment: Wow.. thanks guys ... I also have one more question. Can I change the pwm characteristics on the run via Usb commands ? Like I want to change the frequency as I want just by sending command over Usb instead of reprogramming the chip ?

Comment: If you program the MCU the proper way, yes this can be done. The PIC allows you to set the PWM frequency on-the-fly. (just look at the data sheets for the PWM component of the PIC you did choose)

Comment: Thanks ! for now ill begin my work on PIC18F4550 and then migrate to other.